# Javac API - Specifiying compilation units in a ProcessingEnvironment

Tags: java

I'm using a ProcessingEnvironment to get a `JavaTask` instance, i.e.

```
ProcessingEnvironment env = // my processing environment
JavacTask ct = JavacTask.instance(env);
```

But what I can't figure out is how am I supposed to specify the compilation units (i.e. the files to be compiled).

For instance, there is another way of getting a `JavaTask` instance where you can specify files in a pretty straightforward manner

```
java.util.List<JavaFileObject> files = // files to be compiled

JavaCompiler tool = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
JavacTask ct = (JavacTask)tool.getTask(null, null, null, null, null, files);
```

where various params of `getTask` are as follows:

```
javax.tools.JavaCompiler public abstract JavaCompiler.CompilationTask getTask(java.io.Writer out,
                                                 javax.tools.JavaFileManager fileManager,
                                                 javax.tools.DiagnosticListener<? super javax.tools.JavaFileObject> diagnosticListener,
                                                 Iterable<String> options,
                                                 Iterable<String> classes,
                                                 Iterable<? extends javax.tools.JavaFileObject> compilationUnits)
```

Currently, this is how I'm preparing my ProcessingEnvironment

```
Context context = new Context();

JavacProcessingEnvironment env = JavacProcessingEnvironment.instance(context);

env.setProcessors(<list of some annotation processors>);
```

I think there is a way to specify compilation units in either ProcessingEnvironment or in the context it's made from, which I am missing. So my question is - what is that way?